# The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have already checked many similar issues in so many forums.But not exactly similar to mine. Also I do not want to move my login method to base.

Code :

**LoginTest.cs**

```
using test_TestAutomation.PageObjects;
using NUnit.Framework;    

namespace test_TestAutomation.TestClasses
{      
    class LoginTet
    {
       // public IWebDriver driver;

        [Test]
        public void LoginSuccessCheck()
        {    
            LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
            login.LoginSuccess();    
        }
    }
}
```

**Base.cs**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using NUnit.Framework;   

namespace test_TestAutomation.TestClasses
{
    class Base
    {    
        public static IWebDriver driver;       
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();                                    
        }  

        [Test]
        public void OpenURL()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com");    
        }    

        [TearDown]    
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

**LoginPage.cs**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using test_TestAutomation.TestClasses;
namespace test_TestAutomation.PageObjects
{        
    public class LoginPage
    {      
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Email")]
        public IWebElement LoginEmailTxtLocator;

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Password")]
        public IWebElement LoginPasswordTxtLocator;

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#loginForm > div > div > form > div:nth-child(5) > div > input")]
        private IWebElement BtnLogin;    

        public LoginPage()
        {    
            PageFactory.InitElements(Base.driver, this);
        }

        public LoginPage LoginSuccess()
        {               
            LoginEmailTxtLocator.SendKeys("emailtest@gmail.com");
            LoginPasswordTxtLocator.SendKeys("xxxxxxx");
            BtnLogin.Click();
            return this;
        }    
    }
}
```

**Exception :**

Result Message: 
System.ArgumentException : The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null

**Stackstace:**

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.PageFactory.InitElements(Object page, IElementLocator locator, IPageObjectMemberDecorator decorator)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.PageFactory.InitElements(ISearchContext driver, Object page)
```

Comment: SearchContext in your case refers to the driver instance. This is still null as 
 it is instantiated in the constructor of Base which is never called. Should work if you create an object of Base

Comment: @Grasshopper - Instead of that what If I extend base? Would that work?

Comment: should work. do not know much about c# but guessing a static constructor would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you extract the test `OpenURL` from `Base` to `LoginTest` and only do setup and teardown in Base. Then let `LoginTest` inherit from `Base`.

**Base.cs**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace test_TestAutomation.TestClasses
{
    public class Base
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginTest.cs**

```
using test_TestAutomation.PageObjects;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace test_TestAutomation.TestClasses
{
    class LoginTest : Base
    {
        [Test]
        public void OpenURL()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com");
        }

        [Test]
        public void LoginSuccessCheck()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com");
            LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
            login.LoginSuccess();
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginPage.cs**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using test_TestAutomation.TestClasses;

namespace test_TestAutomation.PageObjects
{
    public class LoginPage
    {
        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Email")]
        public IWebElement LoginEmailTxtLocator;

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Password")]
        public IWebElement LoginPasswordTxtLocator;

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#loginForm > div > div > form > div:nth-child(5) > div > input")]
        private IWebElement BtnLogin;

        public LoginPage()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(Base.driver, this);
        }

        public LoginPage LoginSuccess()
        {
            LoginEmailTxtLocator.SendKeys("emailtest@gmail.com");
            LoginPasswordTxtLocator.SendKeys("xxxxxxx");
            BtnLogin.Click();
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```